# How to get all the paths of files inside a specific directory in JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Let's say we have a site with this address: `https://example.com` and we have a directory inside like: `https://example.com/directory`

And that's all we know, we don't know what folders are inside `directory` folder.

How to get all the paths of files inside the `directory` folder and pass the result to a javascript array:

The desired result would be something like this in javascript:

```
let paths = [

'https://example.com/directory/audio/song_1.mp3',
'https://example.com/directory/audio/song_2.mp3',
'https://example.com/directory/picture/image_1.png',
'https://example.com/directory/picture/image_2.jpg',
'https://example.com/directory/movie/clip.mp4',

];
```

I have tried all the possible solutions on the net but it seems that I can't find a working one without help.

one level above the `directory` folder I have the test.php:

```
    <?php
    function getDirContents($dir, &$results = array()){
        $files = scandir($dir);

        foreach($files as $key => $value){
            $path = realpath($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value);
            if(!is_dir($path)) {
                $results[] = $path;
            } else if($value != "." && $value != "..") {
                getDirContents($path, $results);
                $results[] = $path;
            }
        }

        return $results;
    }

echo json_encode(getDirContents('directory'));
```

It returns the result like this:

> "/storage/ssd4/693/8074693/public_html/directory/audio/song_1.mp3"
>   [3]=> string(72)
>   "/storage/ssd4/693/8074693/public_html/directory/audio/song_2.mp3"
>   [4]=> string(72)
>   "/storage/ssd4/693/8074693/public_html/directory/picture/image_1.png"
>   [5]=> string(75)
>   "/storage/ssd4/693/8074693/public_html/directory/picture/image_2.jpg"
>   [6]=> string(61)
>   "/storage/ssd4/693/8074693/public_html/directory/movie/clip.mp4" [7]=>
>   string(73)

The javascript code thanks to @[mamoun othman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/896358/mamoun-othman):

```
$(document).ready( function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../test.php',
            data: 'id=testdata',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result)
            },
        });

});
```

I have script.js and index.html in another folder at `https://example.com/script`.

I can log the PHP `$results` using ajax call but still, I get system file paths instead of corresponding URLs!

Comment: When you read from the file system, you get file system paths. If you want the corresponding URLs instead - then you will have to generate them from those. (Like by stripping off what DOCUMENT_ROOT is set to.)

Comment: _“And also I have issues with getting the PHP array via ajax call and fill the javascript array.”_ - if you want help with that, you need to start with a proper problem description. [ask], [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `var_dump()` use `json_encode(getDirContents('directory'))`, the only way to get all paths in the directory, is to use PHP to loop through files and return the output as JSON or XML (or maybe text but then you have to parse it), JSON is the way to go in your case, all you have to do is request the path of this php script using Ajax:

```
<?php
function getDirContents($dir, &$results = array()){
    $files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.'));;
    foreach($files as $key => $value){
        $path = $dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value;
        if(is_dir($path)) {
          getDirContents($path, $results);
        } else {
          // change this to https if you have HTTPS
          // or have it as a variable like this :
          // $protocol = ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
          $directory_path = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
          $results[] =  'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . str_replace($directory_path, "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) .$path;
        }
    }

    return $results;
}

echo json_encode(getDirContents('directory'));
```

For Ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../test.php',
    data: 'id=testdata',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result)
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer plus one, but still I get the system paths instead of URLs, can you please help me with that..

Comment: You are welcome! sure I can help so you want to have the file name only without the full path, right?

Comment: I want the file paths with my site domain like `'https://example.com/directory/audio/song_1.mp3'` not `"/storage/ssd4/693/8074693/public_html/directory/audio/song_1.mp3"`

Comment: Ok, will check and get back to you soon!

Comment: I updated my answer, please have a look, I did a small revamp!

Comment: That was AWESOME... Actually you have an improvement too... folders with no files dosn't include in the results and that's a great enhancement. But there is a little bug I got `"https://reed123.000webhostapp.com/test.phpdirectory/Courses/audios/horse.mp3", `  instead of `"https://reed123.000webhostapp.com/directory/Courses/audios/horse.mp3", ` . The `test.phpdirectory` should be just `directory`..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207408/discussion-between-mamoun-othman-and-foxer).

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit too late, but maybe for someone in the future.

I got all my file paths with this JS code.

```js
let htmlContainer = document.createElement('div');                  

fetch("http://192.168.0.9:5500/assets/img/gallery/project-1", {
        headers : { 
      'Content-Type': 'text/html',
      'Accept': 'text/html',
      
     }
}).then(response => response.text())
    .then((stringHtml) => {
        htmlContainer.innerHTML = stringHtml;            //convert plain text to Html to have   
                                                         //acces to its elements
                                                         
        //htmlContainer will containe html representation
        //of our project diretories and files, so from there
        //will be able to get files paths
       console.log( Array.from(htmlContainer
                            .querySelector('#files')
                                .querySelectorAll("li>a"))
                                    .map( x => x.getAttribute('href'))) //will print an array
                                                                        //with all file and direcotory paths in our directory
        
    })
```